# How to create custom StaticFileMiddleware and redirect request to needed folder

Tags: middleware, asp.net-core-6.0, document-root

My site with Asp.Net Core 6 hes custom root folder for static files, different from folders with configuration, folders with Program.cs/vb, folders with View, folders with Area, folders with Controllers.

Parts of static files from this custom root working fine, but other static files don't working.

[image: Custom root for static files]

I try to intercept request to static files and manually redirect all request to my root folder with static files.

I write this code for this interception.

```
    App.Use(Async Function(context, [next])
                Dim CurrentEndpoint = context.GetEndpoint()
                If (CurrentEndpoint Is Nothing) Then
                    Debug.WriteLine($"RequestPath {context.Request.Path} endpoint nothing.")
                    Dim StaticOptions As StaticFileOptions = New StaticFileOptions With {.FileProvider = New PhysicalFileProvider(Builder.Configuration("StaticFilesRoot"))}
                    Dim Opt As IOptions(Of StaticFileOptions) = Options.Create(StaticOptions)
                    Dim StaticMiddleware = New StaticFileMiddleware(
                    Async Function()
                        Await [next](context)
                    End Function,
                    Environment,
                    Opt.Value,
                    LoggerFactory)
                Else
                    Await [next](context)
                End If
            End Function)
```

But my attempt to intercept "wrong" request and manually redirect it to needed folder is failed. Because I maybe made mistake to create StaticFileMiddleware.

```
 Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics: Information: Request starting HTTP/2 GET https://localhost:7168/scripts/script.js - -
 RequestPath /scripts/script.js endpoint nothing.
 Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware: Error: An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
 System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.StaticFileOptions' to type 'Microsoft.Extensions.Options.IOptions`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.StaticFileOptions]'.
    at FrontEnd.Program._Closure$__12-0._Lambda$__10(HttpContext context, RequestDelegate next) in G:\Projects\CryptoChestMax\FrontEnd\FrontEndCode\Program.vb:line 256
    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

Unfortunately, I can not understand what I doing wrong and what cast is not valid. If I try to create custom middleWare in debugger than there are not error, but attempt to processing request with my new StaticMiddleware get me error.

[image: New options]

What wrong in my StaticMiddleware?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In current question this is my mistake with Root for StaticHtmlFiles, but my way to detection error can be helpful to any programmer.

I have create this Route Analyzer and finally understand that I have wrong variables loaded as Root for static files.

```
    'Route anylizer
    App.Use(Async Function(context As HttpContext, NextRequestDelegate As RequestDelegate)
                Dim CurrentEndpoint = context.GetEndpoint()
                If (CurrentEndpoint Is Nothing) Then
                    Debug.WriteLine($"RequestPath {context.Request.Path} endpoint nothing.")
                    Dim StaticOptions As StaticFileOptions = New StaticFileOptions With {.FileProvider = New PhysicalFileProvider(Builder.Configuration("StaticFilesRoot"))}
                    Dim Opt As IOptions(Of StaticFileOptions) = Options.Create(StaticOptions)
                    Dim NewEnvironment As IWebHostEnvironment = Environment
                    NewEnvironment.ContentRootPath = Builder.Configuration("StaticFilesRoot")
                    NewEnvironment.WebRootPath = Builder.Configuration("StaticFilesRoot")
                    Dim StaticMiddleware = New StaticFileMiddleware(
                        Async Function()
                            'Await NextRequestDelegate(context)
                            Dim StaticFile As IFileInfo = Opt.Value.FileProvider.GetFileInfo(context.Request.Path)
                            If Not StaticFile.Exists Then
                                Await context.Response.WriteAsync("File is nothing")
                            Else
                                Await context.Response.SendFileAsync(StaticFile)
                            End If

                        End Function,
                        NewEnvironment,
                        Opt,
                        LoggerFactory)
                    Await StaticMiddleware.Invoke(context)
                Else
                    Debug.WriteLine($"Endpoint: {CurrentEndpoint.DisplayName}")
                    Dim Endpoint As RouteEndpoint = TryCast(CurrentEndpoint, RouteEndpoint)
                    Debug.WriteLine($"RoutePattern: {Endpoint?.RoutePattern.RawText}")
                    For j As Integer = 0 To CurrentEndpoint.Metadata.Count - 1
                        Debug.WriteLine($"Endpoint Metadata {j}: {CurrentEndpoint.Metadata(j)}")
                    Next
                    Await NextRequestDelegate(context)
                End If
            End Function)
```

[image: Is static file present in custom root?]

And anybody can create custom message, custom code or custom header for missing files by this way

[image: custom response for missing files]